# material-UI datepicker is not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

material-UI date picker is not working. This is not working so how to do. I am using material-UI and Reactjs. So please help me how to do.

```
    const minDate = new Date();
const maxDate = new Date();
minDate.setFullYear(minDate.getFullYear() - 1);
minDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
maxDate.setFullYear(maxDate.getFullYear() + 1);
maxDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

this.state = {
  minDate: minDate,
  maxDate: maxDate,
  autoOk: false,
  disableYearSelection: false,
};

render(){
    return(
      <DatePicker
        floatingLabelText="Ranged Date Picker"
        autoOk={this.state.autoOk}
        minDate={this.state.minDate}
        maxDate={this.state.maxDate}
        disableYearSelection={this.state.disableYearSelection}
      />
   )
}
```

Comment: what is issue you are facing? this looks ok

Comment: What version of Material-UI are you using ?

Comment: I am using material ui version this "material-ui": "^0.18.1",.

Comment: Its looking correct but its not responding anything

Comment: Are you updating state anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is like the datepicker is not shown when you click it then I guess you are missing react-tap-event-plugin. This plays a trick for datepicker to work. You need to install this and add the below in your application

```
 var injectTapEventPlugin = require("react-tap-event-   plugin");
injectTapEventPlugin();
```